# Copy images using a single dos command

Tags: windows, file-management, cmd.exe

I'm wondering if it's possible to copy only images files from a directory. For example, if source directory has:

> a.jpg b.gif c.png d.txt

I want to copy only the images using one command, to get this in the destination directory:

> a.jpg b.gif c.png

Comment: i retagged "windows" and "cmd" assuming you're using the CMD terminal on Windows NT/2k/XP/Vista/7.  if you're actually using DOS (meaning MS-DOS 6.22 or earlier, or FreeDOS or another DOS variant), please retag with "dos".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At command prompt:

```
FOR %X IN (*.png *.jpg *.gif) DO COPY %X Destination
```

In a .bat or .cmd script:

```
FOR %%X IN (*.png *.jpg *.gif) DO COPY %%X Destination
```